# PyInstaller could i set a relative path for --icon or --add-data with --specpath [other directory]?

Tags: pyinstaller

I ran pyinstaller from python code like following.

```
import sys, os
import PyInstaller.__main__

args = [ ... ,
    '--icon', './myicon.ico',
    '--add-data', './resource;resource',
    '--workpath', './build',
    '--specpath', './build',
    '--distpath', './bin',
]

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PyInstaller.__main__.run(args)
```

Then i failed and got a message `Unable to find "build\resource" when adding binary and data files`.

A freezing succeeded when i removed the option ['--specpath', './build'].
I guess that pyinstaller use the specpath as a root directory to search data files.
Similar things occurred with --icon option, building failed with --specpath.

Can I use relative path relative to script file not specfile..?
or Can I specify a root directory for icon, data files or binary files..?
I am using python 397 and pyinstaller 4.7.

Answer (score -2):

I got an answer about this post in other. The relative path of resources always must be relative to the spec file path.
Or can use the full path.

For example about the above, following can be added before running `pyinstaller.run` to make it working.

```
for i, a in enumerate(args):
    # when i is an index of path
    args[i] = os.path.abspath(a)
```

It changes all path to full path and makes the script working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer is very clear.